# Изменение зеркала репозиториев в OpenBSD

Tags: repository, bsd, openbsd

Мне нужно изменить зеркала репозиториев в OpenBSD 6.2 потому что OpenBSD не обновляется. 
Сейчас у меня стоит ftp.openbsd.org и хотел бы изменить на ftp2.fr.openbsd.org/, потому что я нахожусь в Франции. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export PKG_PATH="http://ftp2.fr.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/$(uname -r)/packages/$(arch -s)/"
```

Или изменить `installpath = ftp.openbsd.org` на `installpath = ftp2.fr.openbsd.org` в `/etc/pkg.conf`